# Linux expect spawn can not find file

Tags: linux, bash

I wrote a expect script named load_data.exp

```
#!/usr/bin/expect

spawn "osm2pgsql -s -l -d postgres -W -U postgres -H localhost -P 5432 --hstore /absolute/path/to/bruges_belgium.osm"
expect "Password:" {send "mysecretpassword"}
```

change access by

```
chmod +x load_data.exp
```

run it by

```
./load_data.exp
```

the file definitely exits, it gives me error

```
spawn osm2pgsql -s -l -d postgres -W -U postgres -H localhost -P 5432 --hstore /absolute/path/to/bruges_belgium.osm
couldn't execute "osm2pgsql -s -l -d postgres -W -U postgres -H localhost -P 5432 --hstore /absolute/path/to/bruges_belgium.osm": no such file or directory
while executing
"spawn "osm2pgsql -s -l -d postgres -W -U postgres -H localhost -P 5432 --hstore /absolute/path/to/bruges_belgium.osm""
(file "./load_data.exp" line 6)
```

osm2pgsql is installed and can be run directly in terminal the following sentence

```
osm2pgsql -s -l -d postgres -W -U postgres -H localhost -P 5432 --hstore /absolute/path/to/bruges_belgium.osm
```

so there is a problem with spawn, I guess

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the error suggests, it's trying to find a program not called `osm2pgsql`, but one called `osm2pgsql -s -l -d postgres -W -U postgres -H localhost -P 5432 --hstore /absolute/path/to/bruges_belgium.osm` including all the spaces and dashes as part of the executable name.  Remove the quotes from the spawn command:

```
spawn osm2pgsql -s -l -d postgres -W -U postgres -H localhost -P 5432 --hstore /absolute/path/to/bruges_belgium.osm
```

Answer (score 1):

Try specifying absolute path to osm2pgsql (acquired by command '`which osm2pgsql`')

Comment: that is  "/usr/bin/osm2pgsql"

Comment: I think you shouldn't use quotes for spawn command. Try `spawn [/usr/bin/osm2pgsql -s -l <...> ]`